# IIS 7.5 not compressing JSON when set in application web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been working on enabling JSON compression from one of our MVC3 sites. From various articles I've read it seems as though I should be able to set the `application/json; charset=utf-8` MIME type in the applications web.config file. But doing so does not enable compression. But when added to the applicationhost.config file, it works. Am I missing something here?

My application web.config has the following added to it:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7.5. I've also installed & enabled Dynamic Compression for the site in question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I do not wish to enable JSON compression for the entire server.

Comment: Please have a look at this post: stackoverflow.com/a/7634875/1131855

I was not able to edit applicationHost.config via Notepad++. This link suggested a console command which worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`HttpCompression` section is defined `AppHostOnly` in `ApplicationHost.config` which prevents you from setting its properties in web.config.

The compression module reads only the server level properties from 'ApplicationHost.config' so even if you unlock the section (with `appcmd` or `overrideModeDefault="Allow"`), settings on lower level will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for that, it cleared up the confusion. It turns out that even if you add a <location> element to the ApplicationHost.config for a site to try and allow HttpCompression at the site level, it remains locked because of the AppHostOnly attribute. The only way is to add the application/json MIME type to the "global" <httpCompression> section in ApplicationHost.config & thus turn it on for all sites on the server.

Comment: @tpeczek `The compression module reads only the server level properties from 'ApplicationHost.config'` Do you have a source for that? I can't find *anything* official from Microsoft, even though it absolutely looks to be the case, especially with IIS8+