# Enabling basic http authentication in IIS on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For a demo site on Elastic Beanstalk, I'd like to enable basic authentication in IIS (not in the app, but instead have IIS handle it).  I can't find how to configure IIS to do this - you don't seem to have much access to IIS configuration itself.  Any tips on that appreciated, or if I'm missing the boat here.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ebextensions to customize the server.

Create a yaml init.config file inside a folder called .ebextensions in your web application root. Set the contents as follows:

```
container_commands:
  00-iis-features:
    command: dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-BasicAuthentication
```

Read more about ebextensions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html)
Also, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42336644/1165140 on how to modify root IIS config.

Hope this sorts you out.